# Using $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$ to show..

Tags: real-analysis

I must use the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$ to show that $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent does not necessarily imply that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$.

I'm not entirely sure what $f(x)$ is since it doesn't seem to be defined. Is it just some real function? Besides that, i'm not sure how to approach this problem. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$, which is an infinitely differentiable function. We have $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin\left(x^2 \right) dx = \dfrac12 \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}2}$$
but $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin\left(x^2 \right)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You might include the middle step $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^2) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(y)}{y} dy$.

Comment: @Ian Actually the integral is $\frac12\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(y)}{\sqrt{y}}dy$. The easier way to evaluate the integral is to move to the complex plane and end up evaluating the error integral.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, sorry for the error.

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially asking you to prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0 $ is not bi-conditional with a function's convergence by using $ \sin (x^2)$ as a counterexample. In this question, $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function of x.

Comment: Actually, it's just asking about conditional, I believe. And bi-conditional is an odd word - the more common term is "equivalent."